# Drupal sub theme does not inherit the parent css

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-theming

I have a sub theme called `JeanB` whose `jeanb.info` file is like

```
name = JeanB
description = JenB is a new theme.
basetheme = bartik.


stylesheets[all][] = css/jeanb.css

regions[header] = Header
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2012-02-01
version = "7.12"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1328134560
```

The direcory `jeanb` is in `/sites/all/themes` . But this sub theme is unable to inherit the parent css properties, though `jeansb.css` works !

Answer (score 1):

I Think it should be

**base theme = bartik**  instead of : basetheme = bartik.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you----

```
name = JeanB
description = A sub theme of Bartik theme with many regions.
core = 7.x
base theme = bartik

stylesheets[all][] = css/JeanB.css

regions[header] = Header
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

regions[featured] = Featured
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last

regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
regions[footer_secondcolumn] = Footer second column
regions[footer_thirdcolumn] = Footer third column
regions[footer_fourthcolumn] = Footer fourth column
regions[footer] = Footer

settings[shortcut_module_link] = 0
```